# Camper vehicle supplemental insurance in New Zealand

Tags: insurance, new-zealand, campers

We need to buy camper collision and liability insurance for our rented camper in New Zealand.  The camper company excludes any loss due to renters violating local road rules and causing an accident to rented vehicle or other 3rd party vehicles.  If we run a stop sign and hit a car, we pay personally to repair both vehicles.  YIKES!

Do you know of a NZ company or other which offers such additional/supplemental insurance for accidents?

Comment: Do you mean the rental company doesn't offer the insurance they would like you to have? Please note that it is optional to have insurance (yes that is weird) in New Zealand for your car.

Comment: Try emailing this company http://www.tower.co.nz/insurance/Documents/car-insurance to see if you could get regular car insurance. You may also be able to get cover from a travel insurer in your own country, but beware that they may have the same clause in their policy (one insurance company, AA, that I just looked at also has the clause you speak of for their travel insurance).

Answer (score 1):

http://www.nac.co.nz has tourist-specific insurance, but I'm not sure of the exact restrictions - possibly only third party, but better than nothing. Your travel insurance might cover it anyway.

Also, you should check out the road rules before you go http://www.drivingtests.co.nz/roadcode/tourist/